# syntax error after upgrading ansible and python version

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-template

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
found unknown escape character

The error appears to be in line 111, column 25, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- set_fact:
  rollback: " {{ reg3['user_input'] }} "
  ^ here
  We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
  missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
  start a value. For instance:

  with_items:

  - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

```
with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}"
```

After upgrading ansible version to ansible 2.9.17 and python version to  python version = 3.6.8 this syntax error is coming

```
- set_fact:
      reg2: "{{ reg1.stdout[0] }}"
  - set_fact:
      desc: " {{ reg2.split(\"   \")[-1] }} "
  - pause:
       prompt: "confirm Y/N:"
    register: reg3
  - set_fact:
      rollback: " {{ reg3[\'user_input\'] }} "
```

Comment: set_fact: desc: " {{ reg2.split('  ')[-1] }} " or '{{ reg2.split(" "')[-1] }} ',as you want and please show more line of your's playbook, if you want an help.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66353487/edit) and fix the formatting

Comment: Hi Thank you . issue got resolved.... rollback: " {{ reg3[\'user_input\'] }} " is not working with single quotations only working as rollback: " {{ reg3[\"user_input\"] }} "

Answer (score 0):

issue got resolved....

```
enter code here
```

### non working scenario

rollback: " {{ reg3[\'user_input\'] }} "

### working scenario

rollback: " {{ reg3[\"user_input\"] }} "

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful to others if you edited it to fix the syntax, because as it is written SO is swallowing the `\\` characters which are the underlying root issue with your problem. No one would know that just by reading this anwer

Comment: I have edited as you suggested.., Thank You